# Argument data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for argument 1 of substring function

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, substring, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to get the first part of a Guid Field with the TSQL substring function as follows

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Guid, 1, 8) AS Gu FROM MyTable
```

but all i get is this error.

*Argument data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.*

So what is going on here? Should i treat the Guid as pure string first or...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Guid is a bunch of bits, it's just presented to you in a readable format (like any string I suppose) but in this case you have to convert it like Aaron's answer does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(Guid AS varchar(38)), 1, 8) AS Gu FROM MyTable
```

You can't perform `SUBSTRING` directly on a `uniqueidentifier`; you need to cast it to a string type (`varchar`) first.